# How to open Windows explorer with ironPython script from Spotfire Webplayer

Tags: ironpython, explorer, spotfire-webplayer

I use the below IronPython script to open a Windows Explorer to a define path which works perfectly within the client Spotfire.

When I run the same script within the Spotfire **Webplayer**, the Windows explorer don’t open.

No error message is displayed, but I see the below info in the bottom toolbar : Javascript:void(0);

```
# This script executes an external program. 

#Script Parameters
program = 'explorer.exe'
url = 'file://U:/Data/Downloads/'

#A. We need the Process class to execute external programs
from System.Diagnostics import Process

#B. Create new process instance
p = Process()

#B.1 Configure your process
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
p.StartInfo.FileName = program
p.StartInfo.Arguments = url

#C. Start the process and wait 
p.Start()
p.WaitForExit()
```

How can I update my script to make it work also into the Spotfire Webplayer.

Answer (score 1):

On Spotfire webplayer, the script is run on the server. When you create a process to execute a program, it is created on the server. That's why you **can't** open programs (like explorer) on the client.

You can't do this on the client, the best way to do this is probably to have a TextArea in which you put the link of the folder. That way, when a user click on the link it opens the explorer.